# Indenting background image placeholder text to remove from view area

Tags: html, css, image, text, screen-readers

Right, so, I've been informed by a usually high-quality, reliable source that best practice when creating linked images that also include text is as follows:

1. Create some placeholder text inside the anchor element like this:

   `<a class="logoWithText" href="logoWithText.raw">Mr Happy Forever Foobar</a>`
2. Change the element CSS to indent this text outside the viewing window:

   `.logoWithText {
       background-image: logoWithText;
       width = 200px;
       height = 100px;
       display: inline-block;
       text-indent: -9999px;
    }`

The idea is that without doing this, if CSS is turned off on a user's machine, or they are trying to look at it with a screen reader, they're going to have problems viewing the image. But this way they will only see the text if CSS is switched off, and it will be positioned correctly.

But what if the image fails to load for some reason but they do have CSS switched on? The user is not going to see the placeholder text at all... and I'm also pretty uneasy about the whole *put the text all of the way off the screen, as far as it can go* as it seems pretty inelegant and I am worried there are likely to be all sort of unforeseen problems with writing code that's totally against the logic of the language in this way.

Can anyone suggest a solution which would account for *both* broken image links *and* a lack of CSS support on a user's device, and which would be more immediately intuitive to people viewing the code? If there's really no other way of doing this or you guys think my approach is totally wrong or whatever that's ok, I just want to know if I'm going about things the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

Html

```
<a href="http://yoururl.com" class="logo--text">
    <img src="zoidberg.jpg" alt="This is the text that shows up when your image is broken">
</a>
```

CSS

```
.logo--text{ width:200px; height:100px; }
```

Comment: If you use alt text it won't have quite the same effect when the CSS is turned off or a screenreader is used, is my understanding. Alt text will cover the broken images issue though, I do take your point there... but I wondered if there was an all-in-one solution for what seem like two intrinsically connected issues, and one that seems a bit less like a hack...

Comment: if you use an <img> with alt text, it will render the image (and read the alt text in a screenreader) regardless of CSS being turned on/off.  With the background image, if CSS is turned off, you'll have a blank background and plain text.  If the image path is broken, the image tag will still show the alt text, but the background approach will be a blank box with no text (because you've moved it off screen).  I think semantically, if an image is to be interacted with (clicked, read, etc.) an <img> tag is the correct way to go.

Comment: @ryantdecker Would there be circumstances in which a background image would be more appropriate and therefore the solution the source provided would be useful, do you think?

Comment: Bootstrap has a class that does this - providing text for a screen-reader that is positioned outside the view: `sr-only'. The documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/css/) recommends it in various cases, including when using a glyph icon. I have also used this technique in the past when I used to use icon sprites, where it's only possible to use a background image. There may be cases where the layout you want to achieve would only work with a background image, but most likely you could simply put the text over the top instead of in the image, which is much more responsive as well.

Comment: basically, though, there are a lot of uses for it, but it's less likely to be semantic for images, because images that have content, generally should be an <img> element, and backgrounds **usually** don't add value when described for a screen reader.